# WordPress HTTP API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, http

I'm trying to get points from a plugin called myCRED and have those points displayed on another site. This is possible because myCRED has a remote API that works through the WordPress HTTP API. I have the code that allows me to access the API but I'm confused how to use it to echo the point results on to the page. Here's what I have so far

```
$secret_key = 'mysecretkey';
$remote_url = 'http://siteb.com/api/';

$action     = 'GET';
$account    = 'john.doe@email.com';
$point_type = 'my_custom_type';
$host       = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
$token      = md5( $host . $action . $secret_key );

$request    = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'body'   => array(
    'action'  => $action,
    'account' => $account,
    'type'    => $point_type,
    'token'   => $token,
    'host'    => $host
    )
);

$response = wp_remote_post( $remote_url, $request );
```

How do I get my points to echo on to the page? Where do I put this code?

Comment: Also can I use get_current_user(); within the $account variable to add in the current users email?

Comment: Also I would like to point out that I know that the secret key and url need to be changed to my api's but I didn't want to post them publicly.

Comment: What here is specific to the wordpress plugin why couldn't you just call this from your other application?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong here but you currently have two wordpress websites. One is using a plugin myCRED which has an api. You want to use that api from another wordpress website to display information.

You should handle the templating on the client side. I've included an example for enqueuing a script with an nonce and ajax url exposed to be able to communicate to your wordpress backend.

Using wp_ajax, you can create a function which will return your data from the myCRED api and then return that data back to client side who requested it.

The templating should be handled client side which I left for you since I'm unsure of the end goal here.

This example could be turned into a very simple plugin, but for brevity sakes I've shown to just include this in your functions.php file

Wordpress Enqueue Script
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
// functions.php
function my_cred_script() {
  wp_register_script( 
    'cred-script', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/js/file.js', 
    array('jquery'), 
    null, 
    true
  );

  wp_enqueue_script( 'cred-script' );
  wp_localize_script( 'cred-script', 'ajax_object', array(
      'cred_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'cred_nonce' ),
      'ajax_url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
  );
}
```

Wordpress Ajax Reference
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

```
// functions.php
function get_my_cred_data() {
  if(!isset( $_POST['cred_nonce'] ) || 
     !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['cred_nonce'], 'cred_nonce' )) {
    die();
  }

  $secret_key = 'mysecretkey';
  $remote_url = 'http://siteb.com/api/';

  $action     = 'GET';
  $account    = 'john.doe@email.com';
  $point_type = 'my_custom_type';
  $host       = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
  $token      = md5( $host . $action . $secret_key );

  $request    = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'body'   => array(
      'action'  => $action,
      'account' => $account,
      'type'    => $point_type,
      'token'   => $token,
      'host'    => $host
    )
  );

  $response = wp_remote_post( $remote_url, $request );

  echo $response;

  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_cred_data', 'get_my_cred_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cred_data', 'get_my_cred_data');
```

In some javscript file in your theme that was enqueued from the above. We can now call our action ('cred_data') we created in wordpress from the client side. We should get back some json and can template it however we like.

```
function getCREDData() {
  var options = {
    action: 'cred_data',
    cred_nonce: ajax_object.cred_nonce
  };

  $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
      // handle response
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // handle err
    });
}
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you! Turns out there is a bug with the myCRED API due to it not being maintained as they're currently switching the plugin to use the rest API. It returns a 404 error no matter what you do so now I have to figure out another plan of action.